# NamingException loading bean with JNDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.2

I have two stateless EJBs that implement an interface. To load an implementation I'm using InitialContext but it always fails with `NamingException`.

The interface

```
package app.ejb.login;

public interface UserValidation {

    public static final int DBValidation = 1;
    public static final int LDAPValidation = 2;

    public int validateUser(String userid, String password) throws InvalidAccessException;

}
```

The first implementation

```
package app.ejb.login;

@Stateless
public class LDAPUserValidationImpl implements UserValidation {

    @Override
    public int validateUser(String userid, String password) throws InvalidAccessException {
            ........................
    }

}
```

and the second implementation

```
package app.ejb.login;

@Stateless
public class DBUserValidationImpl implements UserValidation {

    @Override
    public int validateUser(String userid, String password) throws InvalidAccessException {
            ..................
    }

}
```

This is the code that calls the implementation depending on a configuration:

```
package app.ejb.login;

@Stateless
public class LoginBean {
.....
.....
UserValidation userValidation = null;
InitialContext ic = null;
try {
    ic = new InitialContext();
    if (flag == 1)
        userValidation = (UserValidation) 
            ic.lookup("java:comp/env/app/ejb/login/DBUserValidationImpl");
    else 
        userValidation = (UserValidation) 
            ic.lookup("java:comp/env/app/ejb/login/LDAPUserValidationImpl");
    }
    catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in InitialContext: " + e.getMessage());
```

This code prints:

> Error in InitialContext: env/app/ejb/login/DBUserValidationImpl
>   -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."app-2.0"."app-ejb-2.0".LoginBean.env.app.ejb.login.DBUserValidationImpl

What is the correct JNDI to load the bean? Isn't the full package path?

I also tried with `java:module/app/ejb/login/DBUserValidationImpl` but got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
java:module/DBUserValidationImpl
```